# Is there any function to Encrypt password other than EncryptByPassPhrase and master key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption, password-encryption

1. I have to encrypt the password in database table.
2. In stored procedure(for login) password will come as input, that password I need to encrypt inside the procedure and match with the encrypted password in my database table.
3. I should not decrypt password.

I tried EncryptByPassPhrase for encryption but the problem here is every time it will generate some new random number. so when I tried to encrypt the input password it generated a different encrypted password and it didn't match with my encrypted password in my db table

Comment: Unless these are passwords for a 3rd party login, You don't need to encrypt them but to [hash them with salt.](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ZoharPeled . but my requirement is like that.I was able to do it by using HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'password') function.

Comment: Hash+salt is not a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieve by using HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'password') it will give the same encryption every time.

Comment: Go read the link zohar posted - this is not secure without salting.

Comment: Which will give to the exact same hash code for the same passwords. and be vulnerable to rainbow table attacks. That's why we use salt. Go read the article, for your user's password safety.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready-made SDK (Virgil Security PureKit SDK) that is an implementation of the Password-Hardened Encryption (PHE) protocol – a powerful and revolutionary cryptographic technology that provides stronger and more modern security, that secures users' data and lessens the security risks associated with weak passwords.

PureKit SDK allows developers to interact with PHE Service to protect users' passwords and sensitive personally identifiable information (PII data) in a database from offline/online attacks and makes stolen passwords/data useless if your database has been compromised. Neither Virgil nor attackers know anything about users' passwords/data.

Comment: The official documentation can be found [here](https://virgilsecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/PHE-Service-Technical-Paper.pdf)